# Products are not visible after update 2.2.8 -> 2.3.3 (CE)

Tags: upgrade, products

After update the category view won't show any products:
"we can't find products matching the selection"

Some products will show up if I filter the results enough, but usually none will show up.

I have tried clearing all the caches multiple times, clearing static files, reindexed, imported the products again, etc. but nothing has helped so far.

Even if I import only 2 products, I got the result "we can't find products matching the selection" in any category. Both of the items will show up in search and in category page if I filter the results.

No errors in log files.

Any ideas?

Comment: how you upgrade using composer?

Comment: Yes, I upgraded using Composer

Comment: what are the steps you did i am also upgrading but getting this error - symfony/process v2.0.25 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.1.0].

Comment: I followed the instructions here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

Answer (score 0):

It might be because in 2.3.3 MSI is introduced, and most probably the products will be out of stock or the salable quantity(Also introduced in 2.3) will be zero.

Comment: Wouldn't this hide the products from search too? And why would the filtering reveal the products if this would be the case? We have backorders enabled, so the out of stock status should not hide the products.

Comment: Yes this will hide the products from search too. I had the same issue, and it was this. So I had to reset the salable quantity of all products.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Sadly this doesn't seem to be the case here.